# Removing randomness-collective-flip pallet from runtime

Tags: extrinsic, rpc, randomness

We recently tried to remove `pallet-randomness-collective-flip` from our runtime. This pallet has been in our runtime since it was created as it was included in the `template-node-runtime`, but we never used its functionality. Our node binary still compiles and runs after we removed the pallet.

But now when we submit an extrinsic we receive this error:

```
RPC call failed: ErrorObject { code: ServerError(1002), message: \"Verification Error: Runtime error: Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed\\nWASM backtrace:\\n\\n    0: 0x61c87 - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind\\n    1: 0x136ee - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_fmt::h8b1b9291c42fd987\\n    2: 0x1055a7 - <unknown>!TaggedTransactionQueue_validate_transaction\\n\", data: Some(RawValue(\"RuntimeApi(\\\"Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed\\\\nWASM backtrace:\\\\n\\\\n    0: 0x61c87 - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind\\\\n    1: 0x136ee - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_fmt::h8b1b9291c42fd987\\\\n    2: 0x1055a7 - <unknown>!TaggedTransactionQueue_validate_transaction\\\\n\\\")\")) }.
```

We are using the `monthly-2022-06` pre-release of substrate.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this particular error is because of this pallet but randomness-collective-flip pallet is important part of blockchain as it provides randomness  in blockchain as our  blockchain lies on concept of randomness.